# Count ID's having only one distinct value in Column B

Tags: sql

I want to count ID's from column A that have only a single Distinct value in column B.

In a coding sense i want to:

```
SELECT Count(ID) WHERE ID has COUNT(DISTINCT(column_B_val) = 1
```

Code ive attempted, where i get error of using a where clause with aggregation

```
SELECT id FROM `x` WHERE COUNT(DISCTINCT(column_B_val)) = 1
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, no images.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from (select id
      from t
      group by id
      having count(distinct column_B_val) = 1
     ) t;
```

Or, `not exists`:

```
select count(*)
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and
                        t2.column_B_val <> t.column_B_val
                 );
```

with an index on `(id, column_B_val)`, this probably has better performance.

Answer (score 0):

correct sql  will be like below

```
SELECT id FROM x
group by id
having COUNT(DISCTINCT column_B_val) = 1
```

you can not use aggregation in where

Comment: that solves it, thanks a lot. I tried the having clause but forgot to use a group by id. Much appreciated.